# Excel Index Match sum all above

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, match

I have the following input table:

| Time | Start | Destination | Time | Origin | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/16/22 | Buford | Covington | 10/16/22 | Covington | 46.65 |
| 10/16/22 | Covington | Morrow | 10/16/22 | Morrow | 341.56 |
| 10/16/22 | Morrow | Ocala | 10/16/22 | Ocala | 26.8 |
| 10/17/22 | Ocala | Columbia | 10/17/22 | Hawthorne | 192.63 |

and I would like to populate Actual Mile and Distance into the following tables:

[image]

[image]

What I am trying to get (not trying to make a color box!)

[image]

[image]

Red and purple boxes - Index match Origin and destination cities

Yellow and Blue box - the same concept as above boxes, but since Ocala is 10/20/22, sum everything from the origin to the destination but not Ocala for the yellow box.

Blank - Since you don't find Cayce before 10/21/22, return null or "".

Green box - Start back again from Ocala to Dacula, and sum all from Ocala to the first Dacula.

I was able to do red and purple, but I got so lost after blue. I am trying to get function that covers all these boxes.

Comment: What you used to sum the other lines and was correct? And what you used and wasn't correct?

Comment: I tried to use =SUM(INDEX(K:K,MATCH(TRUE,(I:I=B5),0)):INDEX(K:K,MATCH(TRUE,(I:I=C4),0-1)), but I don't know how to apply date to the data that I am adding.

Comment: =SUM(INDEX(K:K,MATCH(TRUE,(I:I=B5),0)):INDEX(K:K,MATCH(TRUE,(I:I=C5),0)-1))

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?  O365 simplifies this a lot.  I would go a different direction than trying to accomplish this with INDEX(MATCH()), and how I would do that might depend on your Excel version.  Also, your date logic is complicated.  Is there a way to simplify it by having a trip start and stop date?  For instance, there has to be some logic that determines that 10/20 is part of the trip ending 10/21.  That means adding more complexity to the formula, or, you can make it easier by each trip having a stop AND start date.